# Drupal entity_load is not loading it's related paragraph module items

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I've installed and configured the paragraph module for my custom content type.
And for the paragraph module, I've some fields associated to the content type.

What I am trying is to load the all information regarding this entity.

So for this I use the code below,

```
$node = entity_load('node', array(13), array(), false);
```

But the problem is, it's only loading the node and not loading the items related to the content type.

I am using the Drupal 7.

Do anyone have Idea about this ?

Answer (score 0):

you can load paragraph field like this :

```
$node = entity_load('node', array(13), array(), false);
$paragraph = Paragraph::load($node->nid);
$node->custom_field = $paragraph->field_name->value;
```

Inspired from https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/229961/how-to-get-paragraph-field-values